# Mouse started moving and clickin on it's own in 16.04

Tags: mouse

Today I had this weird occurence where my pointer started moving on the screen on it's own and clicked everything opening up some folders, links etc.

First I thought my computer was compromised so I shut it down by holding the power button for 5 sec. After that I unplugged the network cable.
After rebooting the system without network for further inspections I noticed that the mouse movement and clicking kept going on for a couple of reboots more until it just stoped. I did nothing special to it.

It seemed like it wasn't a unauthorised access. But I had to be sure so I tried to check last logged in users. The 'last' command gave me bunch of rows but there was one that caught my eye

> guest-sz tty8         :1               Mon Nov  7 16:15 - down   (00:08)

Can anyone tell me is this normal logon?
Also if someone can help me with futher inspection of the incident that would be great.

Comment: What happens when you boot an Ubuntu LiveCD/USB, or another OS, or another computer?

Comment: Do you mean what happens with the mouse or something else?
I assume that there won't be any differences when booting with (in my case) USB because the booting up normally isn't acting up anymore.
If you could tell me what to look for when booting up by other methods I can test it and see.

Comment: For example, boot your Ubuntu installation USB/CD (or make one), and check out the behavior of your mouse over a certain period of time (let it run for a while).

Comment: Is there a reason for doing so if the same thing doesn't happen anymore in normal boot? Should I first see if it still occurs on normal use and then try out your suggestion?

Comment: I'm simply wondering whether it may be a driver or hardware issue.

Comment: OK. I'll try it out if it starts to do it again in normal  boot. Can you tell me if that tty8 logon is normal?